# Does glTextureStorageSubImage2D exist?

Tags: opengl

The OpenGL SuperBible [mentions glTextureStorageSubImage2D](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nwo0CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT981&lpg=PT981&dq=gltexturestoragesubimage2d&source=bl&ots=LpPMWjKtq8&sig=YrK4Hatro5CFcAstr5MSo34C04E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6itGQ59HZAhVE5mMKHaPxCloQ6AEIJzAA); however, a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=gltexturestoragesubimage2d&oq=gltexturestoragesubimage&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57.3359j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) currently shows no other mention of this function and I can not find any prototype or signature anywhere.

Does this call actually exist and if so, what are its parameters?

Comment: Never heard of anything like that. And it doesn't make sense, `glTex[ture]Storage` allocates, `glTex[ture]SubImageXD` copies. Those are two entirely orthogonal concepts which modern GL makes a big deal about explicitly separating. I'm pretty sure they just mean the latter there. However, with the SuperBible I also don't really know if they might not have added their own custom functions (even if it would be odd to name them like genuine GL calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function. Given the context of the text, it is almost certainly referring to `glTextureSubImage*`.